# NodeJs + PhantomJs page content doesn't have all the elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, phantomjs

Hi I am trying to parse a website which has live football scores. Using NodeJS and PhantomJS together ([phantomjs-node](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node)). The thing is I am not able to run JQuery in `page.evaluate` on an element because I assume page content doesn't have the element I want to parse. Here I have a simple example and the element I can't see is called "resultsList". If I run `$("#resultsList").html()` on the console of a web browser I can get the inner html though.

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

async function getHtml() {
    const instance = await phantom.create([
        "--load-images=false"    
    ]);
    const page = await instance.createPage();

    await page.on("onResourceRequested", function(requestData) {
        console.info('Requesting', requestData.url)
    });

    const status = await page.open('http://www.mackolik.com/canli-sonuclar');
    console.log("STATUS: " + status);

    const content = await page.property('content');
    //console.log(content);

    const result = await page.evaluate(function() {
                        return $("#resultsList").html();
                   });

    console.log("Result : " + result);
    await instance.exit();
};

getHtml();
```

And the latest lines of the output is

```
Requesting http://track.adform.net/Serving/TrackPoint/?pm=775868&ADFPageName=Master%20tag&ADFdivider=%7C&ord=192742255982&Set1=en-US%7Cen-US%7C1024x768%7C32&ADFtpmode=3&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mackolik.com%2FGoogleBanner.htm%3Fv%3D1.150&atdt=.Wa44j1e3NlY5BSo9z4ofjb75PaK4Vpjt3Q9cUVlOrXTAxw63UYOKES5jfyEwHXXTSHCSPxQEt05oaYAhrcpMxE6DBUrizAjVlpSnGmfDnxf7_OLjLnidPZW2AUMnGWVQdgMVQdgGgeVjrkRGjftckcKyAd65hz7YOK2w5ADwIlUjVsYwQ9dvcpxUlzXJJIneGffMfOz77qZoOSix5ezdstlYyxrtSw5DfiPDKOqUhO3f9puqSySy.aPjgnYVuxISg0QirQjEKZtlGqfstpBSKxUC56MnGWpwoNSUC550ial.rIN96h1P38Z_..hw6LzSIrwyMSu_djmVzgzH_y3EjNrjOxCRg9Vr_0p5DtQWug0Jl5mQeQzJQSuX3jtFTL4z1dyJjjNrjOxCUciL4FQmVurNW5BNlYiJ.lY5BqNAE.lTjV..G1
Requesting http://cdn.dimml.io/static/0025b42fc3958ae34c902ccc8164863b1d4b6019.js
STATUS: success
Requesting http://baltar.dimml.io/flow/oiod/0025b42fc3958ae34c902ccc8164863b1d4b6019.js?clientId=2&dom=www.mackolik.com&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mackolik.com%2Fcanli-sonuclar&gemius_sent_once=1
Result : null
```

As you can see "Result" prints null.

I run with the command `>node --harmony-async-await phantomTest.js`

EDIT: webpage has JQuery library. So, I dont need to use `includeJs()` for adding JQuery.

```
Requesting http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js
Requesting http://cm.cdn.md/js5/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js
Requesting http://cm.cdn.md/js5/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css
Requesting http://cm.cdn.md/js5/jquery.jsonp-2.1.4.js
Requesting http://cm.cdn.md/js5/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom/development-bundle/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-tr.js
Requesting http://cm.cdn.md/js5/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom/development-bundle/themes/custom-theme/jquery.ui.datepicker.css
Requesting http://cm.cdn.md/js5/jquery-autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.min.js
```

Comment: Make a screenshot before page.evaluating - is the element you're looking for present? You should also add some kind of error reporting to your script - maybe there are errors when rendering the page.

Comment: hmm are you talking about page.render() function? And also for error handling is it for page.open() ?

Comment: I've opened that page in Opera. There is no `#resultsList` in there. Perhaps you need to switch into an iframe or there is a typo.

Comment: yeah because that table is being constructed with javascript. you can search for `dvScores` which is a div from the page source. later on search for it in web console and you will see the `resultsList` table under `dvScores` div

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are 2 possibilities

1. the website dont have jQuery inside
   Solution: injectJs("/*absolute path of jQuery in your system*/");

   2. the website have JQuery 
      Solution: Cannot find the particular element.
      Open Chrome execute the same query and paste inside the evaluate.

Comment: Hi Vinayka website has JQuery inside and also `$("#resultsList").html()` returns the related element when I run from Chrome console

Comment: Use InjectJs because IncludeJs in not working as it only add the script but not run it.

Comment: hmm in that way I need to give a list .js files right?

Comment: yeah but the system path like Users/folders/list.js

Comment: oh ok I see. I will try that

Comment: var pg; page.evaluate(function(){ pg=$("#resultsList").html(); },pg);